# In Entity Framework, Should I use List<MyEntity> or IQueryable<MyEntity> in my ViewModel and Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

In the ViewModel, should I create a List or an IQueryable then use it in my View.

**1 Question**
EX:
In the ViewModel I have this property

```
public List<MyEntity> ListEntity {get;set;}
public IQueryable<MyEntity> ListIQEntity {get;set;}
```

Then In the view I Make a loop like that.

```
<ul>
foreach(var e in Model.ListEntity)
{
   <li><%:e.MyInfo</li>
}
</ul>


<ul>
foreach(var e in Model.ListIQEntity )
{
   <li><%:e.MyInfo</li>
}
</ul>
```

**2 Question**

In the repository, Is it better to return an IQueryable or a List of Entity.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re going to be simply looping through the set, then it’s probably best that you use `IEnumerable<MyEntity>`, which is essentially what you’re doing when you’re using a List but without limiting yourself to using a specific type.

You shouldn’t really need to use an `IQueryable<MyEntity>` at the view level as all the expensive querying should have already been done by the time the data gets to the View, and you shouldn’t be doing any real processing at that level—do it all in the Model, or if needs be in the Controller, but not in the View.

Comment: Ok, Is there any difference between List and IEnumerable. And in the Repository, should I return an IEnumerable<MyEntity> Or a IQueryable<MyEntity>

Comment: List implements the IEnumerable interface, so it’s up to you as to which you use. I personally prefer to return IEnumerable as it means my code is less constrained that using a concrete type (eg. List). In the repository, I’d still return IEnumerable as the repository is where you should be doing all the processing work, so there shouldn’t be a need to return an IQueryable collection.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered but I saw this when looking for an answer to my own similar question, and feel wht I learnt from that might help somebody else.

In my code I have my Controller calling a Service to get data from a Repository.

```
var employees = MyService.GetEmployees()
```

This then goes into the ViewModel as a List of Employees.

The Service returns to the Controller, its client, a item of type IEnumerable. It does NOT return IQueryable for two reasons:

1) IQueryable relies on System.Linq. Anyone using my service would have to import this namespace, when they don't need it*.

2) If the client needs filtered data, they need to tell the service e.g.
var employees = MyService.GetCurrentEmployees()  /  GetEmployees(someFilter)

- If they need to do further filtering, they can import the namespace and cast the List to IQueryable and use LINQ to do it.

The service shouldn't assume that the client might want to do filtering and will return IQueryable "just in case".

In my code the Repository will return IQueryable to the Service, because filtering happens here and I want to use LINQ.

I hope this helps somebody :)